# Avoid ffmpeg re encode using complex filter

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I have a list of ts files that will be concatenated to being trim later and encode it in mp4.

All of it is working ok... however the problem I have right now is the file is re-encoded... and that is not what I want, since the ts is already h264 and mp3, so just packing it in mp4 works ok. Actually, this works:

```
ffmpeg -i file.ts -c copy file.mp4
```

But this is not:

```
ffmpeg -i videohls-1935m-index.ts -y -filter_complex \
[0:v]trim=0:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[0:a]atrim=0:10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
[0:v]trim=30:90,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
[0:a]atrim=30:90,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
[0:v]trim=100:200,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
[0:a]atrim=100:200,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
[0:v]trim=250:350,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
[0:a]atrim=250:350,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; \
[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[out] \
-map [out] \
-c copy \
videohls-1935m-index.mp4
```

Obviously it will not "copy" the codecs because the output comes from a virtual exit that is mapped to [out] (or something like that... honestly I don't know exactly how it works, but I know is like that), so it does not have a "codec" per say... so it cannot copy it.

This means I have 2 problems:

1. The file is tinier, which is not bad at all, but...
2. The file is re encoded... so the quality is less also.

How can I avoid this to keep the quality of the video?

Comment: Video filters work on raw uncompressed frames, meaning they need to be decoded prior to being processed by a filter, and subsequently encoded. Using the "copy" codec actually disables filters for this stream, see http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Stream-copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply... Question: then there is no any way for me to do this faster? I want to keep it simple and fast. So I can do it maybe by first creating the files and then concatenate them. Do you think that will be better than this way?

Comment: Just a reminder that if you have additional `ffmpeg` cli usage questions they should be asked at [su] instead. Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions only. It would be best if this question got migrated.

Comment: How can I migrate it?

Comment: I guess you can click the flag link and ask for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Filtering requires re-encoding**, but you have another option:

## 1. Make each segment

What you can do instead is [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) each segment using `-ss` and `-t` or `-to` with `-c copy`.

- Example to skip first 10 seconds and make 20 second output:

  ```
  ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input -t 20 -c copy output
  ```
- Example to skip first 10 seconds and stop at duration 30 resulting in a 20 second output:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input -ss 10 -to 30 -c copy output
  ```

## 2. Concatenate

1. First, read the [concat demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).
2. Then, make a list file:

   ```
   $ cat inputs.txt
   file '/path/to/segment00.mp4'
   file '/path/to/segment01.mp4'
   file '/path/to/segment02.mp4'
   file '/path/to/segment03.mp4'
   ```
3. Finally, you can concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output
   ```

### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenating](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: You could also use [the `segment` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) to generate the segments.